# How to compare the entropy of copulas?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, information-theory, entropy, copula

Three different bivariate copulas are shown below with increasing degrees of dependence (parameter $\theta$).

Differential entropy is a measure of  disorder in a probability density like the copula. Without calculating the formula at the bottom, and based on the images alone, which of the three has the most and least entropy? how can you tell, and how do $\theta$ and maximum value $4.8$ factor into the guess of entropy ranking?

[image]
[image]
[image]

We can calculate the differential entropy of each copula using

$$H(c(u,v))=-\int_{[0,1]^2} c(u,v) \ln c(u,v) \hspace{1mm} du \hspace{1mm} dv$$

where the copula density is

$$\begin{align}
c\left(u,v ; \theta\right) = (1+\theta)(u \cdot v)^{-1-\theta}(u^{-\theta}+v^{-\theta}-1)^{-\frac{1}{\theta}-2}
\end{align}$$

(This [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/435599/plot-density-of-copula-clayton) shows a 3d rendition of what the Clayton copula looks like)

Comment: My intuition would be that entropy should increase with the tendency towards uniformity. Thus, pic1 should have highest, pic3 lowest entropy, no?

Comment: If uniformity implies more entropy and therefore more uncertainty, we can say then that the higher that the level of dependence is ($\theta\rightarrow\infty$), the less entropic the copula becomes?

Comment: Not clear to me whether this behaviour is monotone in $\theta$.

Comment: The transforma-shaping of the copula density is a monotonic function of $\theta$ at least. What does the level 4.8 mean in the colorbar? 4.8 of what, is being measured?